# Why can my iMacs see a networked printer but not Windows machines?

Tags: windows, macos, printing, network-printer

I seem to be having issues connecting Windows machines on my network to networked Xerox Phaser 6180 printers. These printers show up and print just fine on all of our iMacs. I've checked and re-checked all of the TCP/IP settings and everything looks fine, I also compared the settings to HP Laserjets we have that are showing up fine for the Windows computers and nothing looks out of place. We also have a Xerox 6700 with virtually the same configuration that is showing up fine, so why not the 6180s? Physical connections seem ok, I can also ping the printers successfully from the Windows machines as well as access their web interfaces via IP on the Windows machines, but when I look for them in the Add Printer list they do not appear, nor do they connect when I attempt to add the printer manually. Any thoughts? Thanks very much!

Comment: The issue is only happening on Windows machines, the iMacs can see the printers without issue, but yes I did try disabling all firewalls on them temporarily, but still no luck.

Comment: Try installing them as "local printer", not "network printer". When asked for the port, create a new Standard TCP/IP port with the printer's IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much for the suggestion! I was able to find a working solution to this after a bit of digging on the Xerox forums. Here it is:

SOLUTION---->

This works if you are having issues adding a Phaser 6180 (as well as the 6280 and I'm sure other models are affected by this bug too) with Windows 7 and greater over a LAN.

From a Xerox support engineer:

"They need to install the global driver, then go into the printers port and make it LPR, with “lp” as the queue name, make sure “LPR byte Counting” is not enabled, SNMP doesn’t matter."

So, to elaborate on this,

1. Download the Xerox Global Print Driver [here](http://www.support.xerox.com/support/global-printer-driver/file-download/enus.html?operatingSystem=win10x64&fileLanguage=en&contentId=133219&from=downloads&viewArchived=false) (current link, this may change but just search for it if it's broken)
2. Run the driver installer. You will get to a screen where the installer will try to discover networked Xerox printers, but of course it won't find the Phaser 6180 because of this bug.
3. Click on the other tab in the installer with the icon that shows a single printer - "IP Address or DNS name"
4. Enter the IP address of the Phaser you are trying to connect to. Click Search. After about 30 seconds of searching for it, a window will pop up saying "No Supported Printer Found." Don't worry, simply click "Install" regardless to install the Global Print Driver.
5. Enter the Queue name (what you'd like to call the printer, so put in Xerox Phaser 6180 or whatever you'd like). Use the recommended PostScript driver (this is what worked for me although I haven't tried the PCLs). You shouldn't have to check off "Download files from the Internet." Click Install, then kick back and wait for it to do its thing.
6. You will hopefully get a window saying that the installation is complete, success, hooray! But we're not done yet! Uncheck "Print a test page" and click finish, because the printer still won't work.
7. Open up the Devices and Printers window in the Windows Control Panel. You should see the new printer added with whatever you named it during installation. Right-click the printer and click on "Printer Properties."
8. In the window that opens, click on the "Ports" tab. Scroll down in the list of ports listed until you see the one that is checked off. It should be something like "X_192_168_1_15 (or whatever IP your printer is)   Standard TCP/IP Port    Xerox Phaser 6180" 
   Highlight this and click the "Configure Port" button.
9. In the new window that opens, select the "LPR" protocol instead of "Raw." Then, where it says Queue name in LPR settings, type in "lp" (without the quotes!). Make sure the "LPR Byte Counting Enabled" box is NOT checked off. SNMP Status Enabled can also stay unchecked. Click "Ok" and then "Close" on the Printer Properties Window.
10. That should do it! Your networked Phaser printer should now work in Windows!